Как проверить включен ли сетевой адаптер в Python?

В компьютере установлены две сетевые карты. Я написал маленькую программу, в которой нужно выводить название активного сетевого адаптера.
например:
if "Lan 1 - вкл"

  root.title("Lan Switcher - Lan 1 enabled")


Использовать модуль psutil
pip install psutil

import psutil

interfaces = psutil.net_if_addrs()

Активную карту можно определить по наличию ip адреса перебрав сущности, которые лежат в interfaces.
